# efficiently dstack arrays from dictionary python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is keyed by date and filled with classes that have an attribute that is a numpy.array. I want to use np.dstack to make one large array from all the arrays in the dictionary. My current code is like this:

```
import numpy as np
#PARTS is my dictionary
#the .partposit is the attribute that is an array of shape (50000, 12)
ks = sorted(PARTS.keys())
p1 = PARTS[ks[0]].partposit
for k in ks[1:]:
    p1 = np.dstack((p1, PARTS[k].partposit))
```

My result is as I expect:

```
In [67]: p1.shape
Out[67]: (50000, 12, 163)
```

However, it is quite slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, values):
...         self.partposit = values
... 
>>> PARTS = dict((index, A(np.zeros((50000, 12)))) for index in xrange(163))
>>> p1 = np.dstack((PARTS[k].partposit for k in sorted(PARTS.keys())))
>>> p1.shape
(50000, 12, 163)
>>>
```

it took a few seconds to stack it on my machine.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('p1 = np.dstack((PARTS[k].partposit for k in sorted(PARTS.keys())))', "from __main__ import np, PARTS").timeit(number = 1)
2.1245520114898682
```

`numpy.dstack` takes in a sequence of arrays and stacks them together as such it would be much faster if we just give it the list instead of continuously stacking them ourselves.

> numpy.dstack(tup)
>
> Stack arrays in sequence depth wise (along third axis).
>       Takes a sequence of arrays and stack them along the third axis to make a single array.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html

I was also curious as to see how long your method would be:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = """
... import numpy as np
... #PARTS is my dictionary
... #the .partposit is the attribute that is an array of shape (50000, 12)
... 
... class A:
...     def __init__(self, values):
...         self.partposit = values
... 
... PARTS = dict((index, A(np.zeros((50000, 12)))) for index in xrange(163))
... ks = sorted(PARTS.keys())
... """
>>> stack = """
... p1 = PARTS[ks[0]].partposit
... for k in ks[1:]:
...     p1 = np.dstack((p1, PARTS[k].partposit))
... """
>>> timeit.Timer(stack, setup).timeit(number = 1)
67.69684886932373
```

ouch!

```
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.6.1'

$ python --version
Python 2.6.1
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This line creates a new list (shallow copy), which is unnecessary overhead:

```
for k in ks[1:]:
```

A more efficient way to do this is:

```
itks =iter(ks)
next(itks)
for k in itks:
```

In addition, you can eliminate repeated lookups with:

```
entries = iter(sorted(((k, v.partposit) for k,v in PARTS.iteritems()), key=lambda(k,v):k))
p1 = next(entries)[1]
for k,v in entries: 
    p1 = np.dstack((p1, v))
```

This will make things slightly faster because it eliminates both copying and repeated lookups in the dict (which although constant time, are not free).

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument` Im on `python 2.6` I think it needs to be `sorted( ((k, v.partposit) for k,v in PARTS.iteritems()), key=lambda(k,v):k)` also `sorted` returns a list not a generator in python2 since I get `TypeError: list object is not an iterator` unless they've changed this in a new version ...

Comment: I'm getting the same errror, but using @samy.vilar 's method fixes it. Thanks, this is the type of 'better python' I was looking for, good use of a generator, etc.